Risk to bounty a question that may be closed
Tomorrow I am likely going to assign a 50 rep bounty (half of my total reputation) to this question. The question has been around since a while, has already been edited and I guess at least one of the senior members of the site has seen it passing.
So far, it has not been closed as a "check my work" question, and I do believe it indeed offers some valuable insights that go beyond the "check my work". The ask is more on the methodology than on numbers.
The criteria by which a question can be closed are not 100% straightforward and I think it sometimes depends on the reviewer or o  the fate.
At a risk of attracting potential "closers" to this question I want to ask: how big is the risk that this question will be closed after I set a bounty to it? I guess the bounty is not refundable even if the question is closed. Is it considered unpolite to close a question after a bounty has been set on it? What is the suggestion? Should I wait a bit more?
thanks!!
p.s. I would see as very sad that I cause my original question to be closed because of my enquiry in here :)

The ability to close questions with active bounties was only recently introduced (literally this week!), so we don't have any habits or statistics around that functionality yet.

@ACuriousMind thanks. what would be your advice? as for your experience how long does it take for a question to be closed? (i would think twice to close a bountied question, but it makes sense after all)

Closure isn't so much correlated with time as with the number of views: the fraction of users who cast any votes, be they up-, down- or close votes, is rather small. Your question has currently 60 views in total, so if you're unsure about its on-topicness I wouldn't take it staying open so far as an indicator either way.

If I were you, I would be worried about the question being closed. Despite your protestations to the contrary ("...I am not asking to check my calculations... check my methodology..."), you are asking for others to check a specific problem and search through a bunch of equations for a mistake.

@hft my question is more on the assumptions I do to calculate kinetic en., $\omega$ and the momentum than on the  passages to prove the equivalence of the methods. the idea is to get a reply along the lines of "yes, your assumptions are right, the equations have to match somehow" vs "no, you are doing wrong assumptions as the angular momentum is instead xyz so there is no point to check equivalence of the two methodologies". but ok thanks, I take your point and I don't want to be too defensive. if you have any advice on what to do (or how to edit the question) you are more than welcome thx:)

I'm not sure how to improve the question. Hopefully someone will answer it.

Given you don't seem to trust the quality of your own question, work first on improving it. Otherwise, you risk that despite the bounty, no-one answers it, and the 50 rep are gone. Do you really want to take that risk?

@NorbertSchuch thanks. yeah I will try. I was thinking of splitting it in two sections. the "assumptions" part and then ask the question "are these assumptions correct" and then add the equations below as an optional section that shows that the two are currently not matching. the risk is that someone will close because I am still asking for validations of assumptions, but at least it will look less like a "bunch of equations to check"

@ebenezer - 'is this right' answers are rightfully closed as homework-like.

@JonCuster @ all  ok seems like there is no way to put my question in a way that is acceptable for this site. maybe the best I can do at this point is to delete it. I've read some where here that deleting an answer is not recommended. do you see anything against deleting this question and posting somewhere else? (not on physics.stackexchange)
